# I want to create a validation rule which will throw an error if account created date is less than 6 months and type='Active'

Tags: trigger, validation-rule

i have used below validation rule ,but the issue is, it will check exact 180 days.there might be chances that there are 31 days in month and then days will be more than 180 days.Please suggest how can i get exact match

```
AND(type ,'Active', Account.CreatedDate > NOW()-180)
```

Comment: 180 days is 180 days. The number of months is of no consideration when doing subtraction between two dates or subtracting a date and a number.

Comment: yes.do you have any solution to consider 6 months subsctraction instead of 180 days .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Datevalue and Addmonths function like

```
DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) < ADDMONTHS (Today(), -6)
```